# How to perform left circular shift on an 8 bit binary internally which are stored in array

Tags: java

This code is just printing the last bits of an array of size (`s[i].length()`). for suppose string is `HELLO WORLD!` its just printing `!` binary value left rotated by one bit. Can someone help..please

suppose `a[i]={202,205}` `a[202]=11001010` and `a[205]=11000011`
After Circular left Shift Output should be like 
`a[202]=10010101` `a[205]=10000111`

```
for (i = 0; i < s[i].length(); i++) { //loop for computing binary value
    System.out.print(" " + dt[i] + " = " );
    int  g=7;
    while(dt[i]!=0)                             
    {
          bindt[g]=Math.abs((dt[i])%2);
          dt[i]=(dt[i])/2;
          g=g-1;

    }
    for(g=0;g<8;g++)
        System.out.print(bindt[g]); 
    }
}
for(i=0;i<s[i].length();i++)          //loop for circular shift on bits
{
    var=bindt[0];
    for(int index=0;index<8;index++)           
    {
        di[index]=bindt[index+1];
        if(index==7)                    
           di[index]=var;
        } 
    }
}
```

The actual code is:

```
    int power = 0,temp;
    int[] a= new int[1000];
    int[] m=new int[1000];
    int[] dt=new int[1000];
    int[] bindt=new int[100];
    int[] ds=new int[1000];
    int[] di=new int[50];
    int[] cov=new int[100];
    int arr[]=new int[10];  
   int var;
    String d = null;
    String e= null;
    int bin[]=new int[8];
    int bink[]=new int[8];
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();    //  Browse File
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    fileName = file.getPath();
     String fn= file.getName();
     System.out.println("File name is :"+fn);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        l = line.length();
        System.out.println("length is " + l);
         System.out.print("Plain Text={");
        while ((br.readLine() != null) || (i <= l))    //computing plain text
        {
            s[i] = line;
             i++;
         }
        //counting no of vowels,consonants,special symbols and spaces
        for (i = 0; i < s[i].length(); i++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if (ch=='e'||ch=='a'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u'||ch=='A'||ch=='E'||ch=='I'||ch=='O'||ch=='U')
                vowels++;
            else if (line.charAt(i)==' ')
                spaces++;
            else if   (ch=='>'||ch=='+'||ch=='}'||ch=='/'||ch=='*'||ch=='!'||ch=='@'||ch=='#'||ch=='$'||ch=='%'||
                    ch=='^'||ch=='&'||ch=='('||ch==')'||ch=='"'||ch==':'||ch==';'||
                    ch=='{'||ch=='['||ch==']'||ch=='?'||ch==','||ch=='.'||ch=='<')
                      ss++; 
            else
                consonants++; 
            ascii = (int) ch;
            a[i] = ascii;
            System.out.print(+a[i]+",");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Static text={");
        for (i = 0; i < s[i].length(); i++) {
            m[i]=(254 - ((a[i]) - (14)));             //Generating static text
                            System.out.print( + m[i]+",");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
        System.out.print("\n");            
        System.out.println("X=number of vowels = "+vowels);
        System.out.println("W=number of consonants = "+consonants);
        System.out.println("Z=number of special symbols = "+ss);
        System.out.println("Y=number of spaces = "+spaces);
        System.out.println("N=Total number of characters = "+l);
        Denominator = ((l-consonants)+(l-vowels)+(l-spaces)+(l-ss));
        System.out.println("Denominator is :"+Denominator);
         System.out.print("Binary Value is: ");
         j=7;
                //loop for finding binary number
                while(l!=0)                            // binary number computation
                          {
                             bin[j]=Math.abs(l%2);
                             l=l/2;
                             j=j-1;
                        }
                        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
                              System.out.print(bin[j]);
                       // loop for obtaining 1's complement          
                        for(j=0;j<8;j++)                                        
                             {
                                if(bin[j]==1)
                                     bin[j]=0;
                                else
                                    bin[j]=1;
                             }
                            System.out.print("\n");
                            System.out.println("Complemented value:")
                            d=Arrays.toString(bin).trim().replace(",","").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(" ","").trim();
                            System.out.println(d);
                            System.out.print("Numerator: ");
                            Numerator = Integer.parseInt(d,2);       //Computing k value
                            System.out.println(Numerator);
                            k=((Numerator)/(Denominator));
                            System.out.println("K =" +k);
                            System.out.print("Dynamic Text:{");   //Generating dynamic text
                            for (i = 0; i < s[i].length(); i++) 
                            {
                            dt[i]=((m[i])+(k));
                            System.out.print( + dt[i]+",");
                             }
                            z=7;
                            while(k!=0)                             
                          {
                             bink[z]=Math.abs(k%2);
                             k=k/2;
                             z=z-1;
                          }
                            System.out.println("}");
                            System.out.println("Binary Value of k is: ");
                             for(z=0;z<8;z++)
                              System.out.print(bink[z]); 
                               }
                            System.out.println("ASCII Values of Dynamic Text is:");
                            for (int h = 0; h < s[i].length(); h++)      //loop for computing binary value
                            {
                           System.out.print(" " + dt[h] + " = " );
                             int  g=7;
                             while(dt[h]!=0)  {
                              bindt[g]=(Math.abs((dt[h])%2));
                               dt[h]=(dt[h])/2;
                             g=g-1;
                              }
```

- List item

  ```
                  }
                          for(g=0;g<8;g++)

                            System.out.print(bindt[g]);                               
                          }
             }
             for(int h=0;h<s[i].length();h++)          //loop for circular shift 
                          {
                for(int index=0;index<8;index++)           
                      {
                          di[index]=bindt[index+1];
                             if(index==7)                    
                                    di[index]=bindt[0];
                            } 
                            }
  ```

  System.out.println("\n Circular shift:" );       //printing obtained circular shift values
      for(int h=0;h
         System.out. print("  “);
        for(int index=0;index<8;index++)
      System.out.print(di[index]);
       }
      }
    }

Comment: I can't see any bit shifting operator here, and that's bad in code that's supposed to perform binary shift operations.

Comment: `i < s[i].length();` using the loop variable for the for-condition indexing s. Is that not a mistake? Maybe needing a new loop counter?

Comment: I think you can use the shift operators `<<` `<<<` `>>` `>>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a test application to create a Java method that would shift the bits in an int array of length 8 one bit to the left in a circular pattern.

Here are the test results.

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] -> [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

As you can see, the bits are shifted one bit to the left, and the left most bit is moved to the right.

And here's the test application code.  It's short, self-contained, and most important, **runnable**.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class BitShifting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitShifting bitShifting = new BitShifting();

        int[] bits1 = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
        shiftAndDisplay(bitShifting, bits1);
        int[] bits2 = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
        shiftAndDisplay(bitShifting, bits2);
        int[] bits3 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
        shiftAndDisplay(bitShifting, bits3);
    }

    private static void shiftAndDisplay(BitShifting bitShifting, int[] bits) {
        int[] shifted = bitShifting.shiftLeft(bits);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(bits));
        System.out.print(" -> ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shifted));
    }

    public int[] shiftLeft(int[] bits) {
        int bit = bits[0];
        int length = bits.length - 1;
        int[] output = new int[bits.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            output[i] = bits[i + 1];
        }

        output[length] = bit;

        return output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A circular shift left on 8 bits:

```
byte rotateLeft(byte b) {
    boolean highBit = b < 0;
    b <<= 1;
    if (highBit) {
        b |= 1;
    }
    return b;
}
```

This utilizes that byte is in two-complements -128 .. 127, and only negative bytes have their high bit set. For an **int** `n` one must cast to `(byte)n`.